# Trying to tweak my sudo configuration

Tags: sudo, 21.10, manpage, visudo, tweak

so I am trying to tweak my sudo configuration(**sudo visudo -f /etc/sudo.conf**) but unfortunately the following errors appeared ???

```
/etc/sudo.conf:16:22: syntax error
Plugin sudoers_audit sudoers.so error_recovery=true
                     ^~~~~~~~~~
/etc/sudo.conf:81:22: syntax error
Set disable_coredump false
                     ^~~~~
/etc/sudo.conf:123:41: syntax error
Debug sudo /var/log/sudo_debug all@debug, all@crit, all@err, all@warn, all@notice
                                        ^
/etc/sudo.conf:124:50: syntax error
Debug sudoers.so /var/log/sudoers_debug all@debug, all@crit, all@err, all@warn, all@notice
                                                 ^
```

Please note that i tried reading the manual of **sudoers(5)** and **sudo.conf(5)** but nothing helped with these errors

Comment: "Multiple arguments may be specified, separated by white
     space." since it points to a "," I'd assume those need to be spaces(?) https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man5/sudoers.5.html

Comment: what version? disable_coredump states:This setting is only available in sudo version 1.8.4 and higher. Same for "_audit": For sudo version 1.9.1 and higher, this is the sudoers_audit plugin.

Comment: @Rinzwind Unfortunately that didn't work... and iam using version 1.9.5p2

Comment: "For sudo version 1.9.1 and higher, this is the sudoers_audit plugin." < sudoers.so isn't understood by parser and results in syntax error just like first error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`visudo` is not intended for editing `sudo.conf`. It works only with `sudoers` file (and files using `sudoers` syntax).

For `sudo.conf` use any editor, for example :

```
sudoedit /etc/sudo.conf
```